# Can any language "deeply" combine or simplify functions?

Tags: optimization, programming-languages, program-transformation

It is common to have two or more functions/methods combined and work as a whole. For examples:

[To "combine" functions in javascript in a functional way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198102/to-combine-functions-in-javascript-in-a-functional-way)

[Is it possible in C++11 to combine functions into a new function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934687/is-it-possible-in-c11-to-combine-functions-into-a-new-function)

However, I was wondering if something like this can be done:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + 1;
Function<Integer, Integer> g = x -> x * 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> h = f.compose(g);
** **
h.toString  //get x-> x*2+1 , what I want
```

The functions are "deeply" combined, which is similar to the simplification of expressions in mathematical software like Matlab.

I know there are some useful techniques in compilaters and I am seeking how it can be done in high-level languages.

By the way, I guess it is theoretically possible using JVM bytecode manipulation but that would be too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that languages usually do not specify the (possible) optimizations to be applied. Optimizations are delegated to *compilers* and *runtime systems*.

Functional languages, such as Haskell, provide many function-based composition features enabling the targetted optimizations. You can look at [function composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition), [lazy evaluation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation), [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) and [higher order functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function).

Please note that a lot of work has been done regarding the specific case of sequence-based computations. See *generators* in Python or the more general/abstract concept called *ranges*. Ranges are available for example in the D and C++20 programming languages.
The composition and the optimization of ranges are achieved at a rather low level and compilers are generally not responsible for their specific optimizations.

Finally, several compilers are able to perform rather clever high-level transformations (see [polyhedral model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model) for loops, [inter-procedural optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) for functions).